# Slack Link Unfurling Dynamic Domains

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is it possible to configure the domains that a bot will unfurl on a per-instance basis?  I'm looking to build a link unfurl where the links will be unfurled from custom domains.

For example, the bot in Customer A's Slack install might need to unfurl `examplea.com`, and the bot for Customer B's Slack might need to unfurl `exampleb.com`.

Answer (score -1):

Your slack application will need the following scopes:

- `link:read`
- `link:write`

You will then need to setup event subscriptions for your app specifically `link_shared` to receive information links posted into Slack that are associated with your app. On the same events subscription page you will need to add the links you want unfurled. You can get more info on this [here](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/link-unfurling#slack_app_unfurling)

Comment: For anyone finding this in the future, this isn't an answer.  Link unfurling specifically says it requires a domain, and changing domains in the list requires the app to be reinstalled.